# How can I add fonts to GIMP 2.8.2 on OS X?

Tags: font

Starting with GIMP 2.8, the application is no longer visibly dependent on X11, so suddenly all the advice I'm aware of for adding fonts to GIMP don't seem to work.

([This worked with GIMP 2.6](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-8648.html))

Now what's a reasonable way to get GIMP to accept new fonts?  Preferably I'd like it to use all the same fonts I've got installed in the system Font Book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add fonts from the preference menu item: 
Gimp-2.8 -> Preferences -> Folders ->Fonts. 
Now simply add the folder containing your fonts.

`/Library/Fonts/` for systemwide fonts 
`~/Library/Fonts/` for user installed fonts

Comment: Is it just me, or doesn't this work with Gimp 2.10?

Answer (score 2):

This **doesn't** meet my desired set up of working with Font Book, but it does work:

1. Create a directory ~/.fonts/
2. Copy fonts into that folder.
3. Press the refresh button at the bottom of the font picker.

Note, I found the idea for ~/.fonts/ by nosing around in /Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/Resources/etc/fonts/fonts.conf